# How can I create an issue with github GraphQL API?

Tags: graphql, github-api

I'm starting to use GraphQL API and I've seen that the mutation createIssue was recently added but I don't know how to use it. I've tried the following but I'm getting errors:

```
mutation {
  createIssue(input:{
    repositoryId:"XXXXXXXXXXXX",
    assigneeIds:"XXXXXXX",
    title:"TestIssue",
    body:"Not able to create an issue"})
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You need first to get the repository id using the following request:

```json
query FindRepo {
  repository(owner: "johndoe", name: "awesome-repo") {
    id
  }
}
```

Then you call the mutation request by replacing the id you've got in the response in `repositoryId` field :

```json
mutation CreateIssue {
  createIssue(input: {repositoryId: "[ID from previous call]", title: "TestIssue", body: "Not able to create an issue"}) {
    issue {
      number
      body
    }
  }
}
```

You can try both call in the [graphql explorer](https://docs.github.com/en/graphql/overview/explorer) and running first the `FindRepo` request and then `CreateIssue`

Answer (score 0):

Or you can do it like this:

[image]

As the previous answer said, you have to find the `repositoryId` first, or you will met the error in the image.

And further more, when you have any issues finding a way to do mutation or query, you can find your answer in the Doc section in the right of the github explorer.